# how to display n day as date assuming 1 year equals 360 days in java?

Tags: java, function, calendar

here is my code,

```
      int txtSubsDay = Integer.parseInt(this.textSubDay.getText());
      int txtDay = Integer.parseInt(this.textDay.getText());
      int txtMonth = Integer.parseInt(this.textMonth.getText());
      int txtYear = Integer.parseInt(this.textYear.getText());
      int daysToSubs = txtSubsDay;

      int convertedYears = (int)(daysToSubs / 360);
      int convertedMonths = (int)((daysToSubs % 360) / 30);
      int convertedDays = (int)((daysToSubs % 360) % 30);          

      Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(txtYear, txtMonth-1, txtDay);
      calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -convertedMonths);
      calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -convertedDays);
      calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -convertedYears);
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
      SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy");
      String lastDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
      String lastDate2 = dayFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
      labelOutput.setText(lastDate);
      labelOutput2.setText(lastDate2);
```

It was what i wanted.////////////////////////////////////////
it saved my time.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Simply use a [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

Comment: Have you tried using the `/` and `%` operators?

Comment: You know a year is 365 days (and 366 once every 4 years)? Not 360.. :S

Comment: I have to assume that one year equals 360 days and 1 month equals 30 days I need a function to make this calculation.

Comment: Could you provide any background to what you're doing and why? I think people will be confused by how you got to this situation and try and help you resolve the problem that way.

Comment: I want to subtract number of days from a date but my number of days will be accepted 1 year as 360 days. For example 27/07/2015 when I subtract 543 days from this day i want to get 24/01/2014.

Comment: The problem is that this isn't properly reversible. What do you define the difference between the dates 2015/02/01 and 2015/01/02 to be? I can only reason that this should be 30. If this is so, then reversing this function will add 30 days (or 1 month) to 2015/01/02 and get 2015/02/02 as a result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Bank Calendar with 30 days each month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277833/how-to-create-a-bank-calendar-with-30-days-each-month)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int totalDays = 548;

int years = (int)(totalDays / 360);
int months = (int((totalDays % 360) / 30);
int days = (int)((totalDays % 360) % 30);

System.out.println("years: " + years + "; months: " + months + "; days: " + days);

// Result: years: 1; months: 6; days: 8
```

Still, I don't really understand why you insist on using 360 for years and 30 for months. If you just want to subtract days from one date to receive the correct date in the past, use this instead:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date dateInstance = dateFormat.parse("27/07/2015");
int daysSubstracted = 548;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dateInstance);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -daysSubstracted);
Date dateInPast = cal.getTime();

System.out.println(dateFormat.format(dateInPast));

// Result: 25/01/2014
```

Comment: when we are calculating the days for retirement insurance we have to assume one year as 360 days that's why i need it. As your calculation it is fine but when it is subtracting it calculates the months which have 31 days that's why if the date is 27/07/2015 and subtracted days 548 I should get 19/01/2015. Not 25.01.2015

Comment: This helped me too much Thanks. I am pasting last version of my code. I got what I wanted thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to find number of days between two dates

```
//we have two dates, now and day 0 
Date d1 = new Date(0); 
Date d2 = new Date();
//substract times from each other, and divide this by number milisecond in day
int days =(int)((d2.getTime()-d1.getTime()) /(1000*60*60 *24) );

//and display your result
System.out.println(days+" days = "+(days/360)+" years "+((days%360)/30)+" month "+days%30);
```

Comment: I did not get how you defined 16475 days.

Comment: @Ert `getTime()` method returns  the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00.   as d1 is January 1, 1970, and d2 is current day, days should be equal to number of days between those dates.